# Trying to make a gradient but it comes out white? What's wrong with my code?

Tags: flutter, dart, gradient

```java
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build (BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [const Color(0x50658C), const Color(0x2D4067)],
              begin: FractionalOffset.topCenter,
              end: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
              stops: [0.0,1.0],
                tileMode: TileMode.clamp
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Followed this 2min video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AFiQsM0gojU&ab_channel=ProGrammer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to prefix your Hex colour with `OxFF`, you have only prefixed with `Ox`. I have provided a demo using your code as an example. I simply prefixed the Hex color with `0xFF`.

```dart
void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build (BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [const Color(0xFF50658C), const Color(0xFF2D4067)], // adjust hex colors
              begin: FractionalOffset.topCenter,
              end: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
              stops: [0.0,1.0],
                tileMode: TileMode.clamp
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a Color value as the hex code but I guess you missed the point that Flutter accept hex codes as Color(0x-opacity-red-green-blue) *the hyphen is just meant to increase readability*. So if you want to give it a red color i.e. 0xff0000 then you need to pass it as 0xffff0000. Note that the first 2 positions after 0x is meant for the opacity value. So now your code would look like the following:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build (BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Container(
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [const Color(0xFF50658C), const Color(0xFF2D4067)],
              begin: FractionalOffset.topCenter,
              end: FractionalOffset.bottomCenter,
              stops: [0.0,1.0],
                tileMode: TileMode.clamp
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```